# how to set indonesia time zone in php

Tags: php, function

I want to try set default time zone of indonesia in php language. but not getting success. i am using this php funciton to set default time zone `date`*`default timezone`*`set();`

this is my code and here i am trying to set default timezine

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Indonesia");
?>
```

if any one know how to do this please help me to set timezone of indonesia

Comment: Geographical time zones are not based on countries but cities (many countries expand through more than one time zone). If you are not getting "Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'Asia/Indonesia' is invalid" please verify you enable [error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting).

Comment: NEVER NEVER NEVER post sensitive information on web!

Comment: Your first port of call [should always be the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timezone in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744893/timezone-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

It's `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');` as there is no `Asia/Indonesia`

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php